# binding click event to swipe

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i display images from a database and i use next and previous for the pagination of the page. what i want to achieve is to bind the click events of next and previous to a swipe event, so when the user swipe from right to left the next link triggers from left to right the previous link triggers. this is the hyperlinks for the texts. 
Previous -`<%=MM_movePrev%>`  Next - `<%=MM_moveNext%>`

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <table width="440" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><div id="holder"> <img src="../<%=(rs_feeds.Fields.Item("pic").Value)%>" alt="" width="430" class="img_round" border="1" /></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="305" class="style52"><a href="<%=MM_movePrev%>"><span class="style5">&lt;&lt;Previous </a></td>
        <td width="173" colspan="-2"><div align="right" class="style52"> <a href="<%=MM_moveNext%>" class="style53">Next&gt;&gt;</a> </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want a script to bind to the links to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a library like [jQuery's touchSwipe](http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html) to accomplish what you're seeking.

Rather than assigning "swipeLeft" and "swipeRight" to the buttons, you'll want to bind it to either the whole page, or some localized piece of it in which swiping is supported. When the particular swipe event you're looking for fires, you can invoke the corresponding next or previous navigation (or simply call .click() on the corresponding button).

Be mindful when assigning swipe events to the whole page as they may interfere with browser-level back/forward swipe gestures.